# This site belongs to.... fix request

Tags: feature-request

When we mark posts as *off topic*, one of the reasons is *this site belongs to...* and the only possibility is **Meta**. However, we all know that 99 out of 100 times it won’t be **Meta**. Most likely it will be **stack overflow**, **graphic design** or even **English**. Some might be moved to **cog-sci** which is in beta to help that site as well.

Anyways, can we have a dropdown with al possible SE sites, or at least the chance to select between the most common ones related to UX.SE (some of them mentioned above)?

Answer (score 2):

Sites can potentially be added to the list if there's a clear need for them. We can see if there's really a need by looking at the stats for the past 90 days.

In the last 90 days there have been 8 questions successfully migrated away from this site.

- 6 to Graphic Design (and 1 rejected migration)
- 1 to meta.ux.stackexchange
- 1 to workplace.stackexchange

Now, (in my opinion) that's not really enough to necessitate a change to the migration process. Currently, if a question should be migrated then it can be flagged for moderator attention and it will be looked at by the moderators and decided upon, which seems to be working pretty well.

One of the issues with migration is that people will regularly suggest sites that aren't at all suitable (usually if people mention anything to do with development they'll be told in comments to post it on StackOverflow, and 99% of the time that's a terrible suggestion. SO is a ruthless site and most questions posted here would in no way be suitable for posting over there. So if the question gets migrated to the wrong place it'll get loads of downvotes, negative comments and will just generally demotivate the poster from contributing to the network as a whole.

There's a bigger post about migration over on the main network meta page: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Jon, I don’t mean migration (although I guess that would be the outcome ) but to have options when we mark a post as *off topic because it belongs to....* Most of the posts I have seen flagged as off topic because they belong to another site are for SO. Anyways, I don’t mean sites nobody will confuse with UX, just the most common

Comment: Really, the only reason to say a question belongs to {place} is because it's believed the question should be migrated over there. Otherwise there's not really any point in suggesting other site destinations. That's the issue though - people will say things belong on sites that they really don't. StackOverflow is a good example. There are loads of comments here from people who've never posted on StackOverflow suggesting some low-quality 'tell me how to build x' question should be reposted there. And they almost never should be.